# TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for int()

Tags: python, types, parameters, int

Why does `int(x = "10")` return `TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for int()` when `int` seems to have a parameter named `x` according to the `int` help string?

```
>>> help(int)

Help on class int in module builtins:

class int(object)
 |  int([x]) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |
```

Edit: I know you can just do `int("10")` or even`10`, but I'd like to know why x is not accepted as a argument name.

Python version 3.8.0

Comment: Your error cannot be reproduced, works on my system. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also you should probably show us exactly what code you're running

Comment: @BramAppel mine is 3.8.0. What's your version?

Comment: Works for me in 2.7.16 and 3.6.3

Comment: I wonder if they changed this to a positional-only argument in 3.8. That's a new feature.

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla the code is in the question. It's `int(x = "10")`

Comment: I reproduced it here: https://ideone.com/UNnibA

Comment: The documentation specifies it’s position-only… https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: I'm getting the same result as OP in 3.7.3. I always thought that functions written in C might not have parameter names, as the interpreter understands it.

Comment: Specifically, it says this change was in 3.7.

Comment: And `str(object = "text")` works with Python 3.8. Why would they not accept `x` in `int`, but do accept `object` in `str`?

Comment: ‘Cause it works as implemented. I don’t think keyword arguments make sense with any of these functions, but they happen to not be consistently implemented in this regard.